# Can the space complexity of a solution using recursive function be O(1)?

Tags: c++, recursion, space-complexity

I have solved [the 98th problem in leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/validate-binary-search-tree/)
and this is my solution:

```
class Solution {
public:
    long long pre;
    bool check(TreeNode *node) {
        if(!node) return true;
    
        bool left = check(node->left);
        bool mid = node->val > pre;
        pre = node->val;
        bool right = check(node->right);
    
        return left & mid & right;
    }
    bool isValidBST(TreeNode* root) {
        pre = (long long)INT_MIN - 1;
        return check(root);
    }
};
```

However, I am not sure if this solution consumes O(n) or O(1) space since someone told me that a recursive function would make use of stack, which makes this solution consume O(n) space.

But in my opinion, pre is not an parameter of a recursive function. Besides, pre's original value won't be needed anymore whenever it is changed since **check(node)** traverse a tree in in-order and whenever a node's value has been compared with pre, it won't be visited in the future, so it only consume O(1) space.

Please help me to clarify the problem.

Comment: Every call to `check(TreeNode *node)` needs additional space for a `TreeNode *` so definitely not O(1).  Without doing the analysis most tree traversals are typically `O(n log n)`.

Comment: each iteration will need to store registers and maybe variables on the stack so each iteration wll take some space

Comment: Are you using leetcode to learn C++? Or just to have fun with some excercises?

Comment: O(n) means you have to go through (x*n)+y steps regardless of recursion or not. O(1) means you can do it in constant time (+y) not dependent on input size, it doesn't mean O(1) is always faster then O(n) if constant time (overhead) is large.

Comment: Can it? Yes it can. But this one isn't.

Comment: @PepijnKramer: "O(1) means you can do it in constant _time_". This is wrong. Big-O notation measures complexity, but is not restricted to _time_ complexity. The question is tagged as space-complexity, and talking about O(1) space complexity makes sense

Comment: My rule: *the maximum recursion level for a recursive function shall be **O(log n)***. Having a **O(n)** level is asking for trouble: it will quickly crash with (not so) big `n`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `O(max tree depth)` space for the parameters and local variables. For a balanced tree, that's `O(log nodes)`, and for a maximally imbalanced tree, that's `O(nodes)`.

The stack frame for the call to `check(parent)` has to exist at the same time as the stack frame for it's call `check(parent->left)` (and similarly `check(parent->right)`). What you don't need is the stack frame of `check(parent->left)` to exist at the same time as that of `check(parent->right)`.